# Got an error in android, but it works in pure java.

Tags: java, android

I've coded some function in a separate java project, it works, and outputs the right result. But when I try to make this .java file in a android project I just got an error saying:

> The method getTextContent() is undefined for the type Node

This is the error I get when I dragged the java file from the java project into the android project..

Here is a bit of the code:

```
for (int k = 1; k<listDist.getLength(); k++) {
        NodeList childs = listDist.item(listDist.getLength() -1).getChildNodes();
        if ((childs.item(k)!=null)&&childs.item(k).getNodeName().equals("text")) {
                totalKM = (childs.item(k).getTextContent());
                finalResult = totalKM.substring(0, totalKM.lastIndexOf("km")); 
                return finalResult;
        }       
    }
```

The error occurs in the variable totalKM.

As I understand Android can construct new Objects based on pure java classes? or isn't that right? What can I do do solve this problem?

My project structure look like this

```
Project1
      src
         com.distance
                    MainActivity
         Services
               Distances
```

The .java file is located in the Services package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.getTextContent() is only available in Android API level 8 and up. You might need to adjust your minimum API level.